# how to send requestBody from the server side to the client in angular2

Tags: angular, frontend, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I am currently using Angular 9 version.

Because of the request of some affiliates, I am using a server-side POST access in universal app.
This is my question.

How to send requestBody from the server side to the client?

Currently I'm using cookies and redirects, but I think this is a bad practice.
Any other ideas?

this is my code.

```
const app = express();
app.post('/complete', (req, res) => {
 const params = Object.entries(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body)))
     .map((e) => e.join('='))
     .join('&');
  
 res.cookie('postParams', params, { secure: true });
 res.redirect('/complete');
});
```

Comment: It wasn't about `Angular`.

Comment: It is Nodejs (Expressjs).

Comment: @paranaan

I used angular universal app. (https://angular.io/guide/universal) and this code is in server.ts

I didn't know how to get redirect requests coming in as POST. So it was handled like this.